# How to override the defaults provided by SPRING BOOT Autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-boot

I have some knowledge of Spring 2.5 development and java but I'm trying to learn more about modern spring including Boot and Data. I'm looking at the project:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/multi-store

I have this example working on my machine but I'd like to override some aspects of the example. For instance I'd like to specify my own mongo database server and name to use in the project. It would appear that the thing to do is create a new bean specifying the mongo datasource, but I'm not sure how to do it in this case.

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import example.person.Person;
import example.person.PersonRepository;
import example.treasure.Treasure;
import example.treasure.TreasureRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Application configuration file. Used for bootstrap and data setup.
 *
 * @author Greg Turnquist
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired TreasureRepository treasureRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    void checkitOut() {

        personRepository.save(new Person("Frodo", "Baggins"));
        personRepository.save(new Person("Bilbo", "Baggins"));

        for (Person person : personRepository.findAll()) {
            log.info("Hello " + person.toString());
        }

        treasureRepository.deleteAll();
        treasureRepository.save(new Treasure("Sting", "Made by the Elves"));
        treasureRepository.save(new Treasure("Sauron's ring", "One ring to rule them all"));

        for (Treasure treasure : treasureRepository.findAll()) {
            log.info("Found treasure " + treasure.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb

Comment: As I have said below I've changed the property in the application.properties file. Is there a corresponding change to the java which is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual properties were in the doc I linked to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

There was a typo in suggestion from Markus - it's spring.data.mongodb.*

I'm still not sure how I can change the db name created though - the default appears to be "test" - maybe this is a default in mongodb?

Comment: The "test" name appears to be specified as part of the "spring.data.mongodb.uri" property. So change its value to something like "mongodb://localhost/mydbname" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

see MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, this is where the autoconfiguration happens.

You can use Spring Boot's property mechanism to override the properties:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

In your case just create an application.properties file with the properties you want to overwrite: eg. spring.data.mongo.host=somehost

Cheers,
Markus

Comment: Can you expand on this a little. I actually already had an application.properties file in my src\main\resources folder which I was using to change the default port of the server. It contains: server.port=8765
spring.data.mongo.host=somehost but the mongo variable is not being used. Should I be adding something to the java to enable it? Where do I get a list of properties I can set?

Comment: In answer to the 2nd part of my comment I just found this great list, I'm still not sure why the host part is being ignored: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: see class:  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.MongoProperties for available properties.

Comment: seems like the prefix changed, in my version it is spring.data.mongo instead of spring.data.mongodb

Comment: I'm still not sure how I can change the db name created though - the default appears to be "test" - maybe this is a default in mongodb?